# Hammock sleeping

Tags: hammock

I love camping and backpacking and have always wondered if it would be better to use a hammock instead of a tent.  I want to know if a hammock is a viable replacement for a tent if you don’t care how many people you can fit.

If it is better for hammock camping what are the things to consider when choosing what to use for a hammock camping system.

If it isn’t better what makes a tent better or is it just that the tent is better in some situations.

Comment: A lot of it is personal preference. I sleep better under a tarp, my son sleeps better on a hammock.

Comment: Hammocks only work if you have trees to hang them from. If you're trying to decide between hammocking or tenting, why not do both and get a [tree tent](https://www.tentsile.com/)?